# Raspbian stuck in read-only after reboot

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, filesystem, readwrite

I'm the new owner of a Raspberry Pi and I'm having trouble with my file-system getting stuck in read-only mode after rebooting the device.

Here's the hardware I'm working with:

Pi: model B

PSU: Samsung GSIII charger 5A 1A

SD: Kingston 8GB (brand new)

input: basic USB keyboard and mouse

video: HDMI

I can install Raspbian using the NOOBS image just fine and once I'm in I can configure and install programs but after a reboot 90% of the time on boot up I get a warning about the file-system being read only and after I log into the shell I can't do any task that involves writing to a file. I can't even launch the desktop. I can run any shell programs I had installed before reboot. I'm rebooting only using the commands `sudo reboot` and `sudo shutdown -h now`. When shutting down I wait for the video to die and the light on the Pi to stop blinking before removing power. I've tried re-imaging the SD card many times and the first boot always works fine, sometimes it lets me reboot once or twice but it always has the same problem eventually. I have a moderate familiarity with Unix/Linux but this is my first attempt at using a Pi. Help!

Comment: Does the SD card have a read-only switch on it?

Comment: Yes and I mercilessly toggled it for good measure. The card showed up as read-write accessible on my laptop, only the pi thought it was readonly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look in `/var/log/syslog` and see if you can find some indication of why. If the filesystem is mounting read-only, the *last* thing in that file will be whatever happened when it was still read-write, since the system cannot log there otherwise.  Which may or may not be helpful...

The kernel's own log is in memory, however, and does not require a writable filesystem to access.  You can view it with:

```
dmesg | less
```

Have a look at that right after you reboot.

**[Then based on that...]**

From the pictures it would appear you have either root filesystem corruption or a bad SD card.  Let's hope it's the former.

Re-flashing the whole image over and over is kind of a brute method and doesn't provide any clues about the problem.  Instead, put the SD card into another linux system (you can use a liveCD), but don't mount it (or `umount` it if it automounts).  Then, if the second partition on the card is `/dev/sdb2`:

```
e2fsck -p -c /dev/sdb2
```

The `-p` means repair automatically, the `-c` is check for bad blocks.  You should see some output about the things being fixed.  This doesn't guarantee everything will be fine, but as long as the corruption is not too extensive, you should be okay.  Do a second run `e2fsck -f`; `-f` forces the check since this time it may be marked "clean".  If that goes okay, the fs is as repaired as it is going to get.

Try booting that, and if it works, you are in luck.  If not, try with another SD card to make sure yours is not defective.

When shutting down, give it a good 15-20 seconds after all activity has stopped before you pull the power.  Quite a few people come here with fs corruption problems, evidently the pi is very sensitive this way.

Comment: What the **** I rebooted again and it works correctly now. I tried rebooting another time just in case and it's still working. I don't want to call this solved just yet but If I'm able to reboot/powercycle a consistently for a while I'll mark it solved.

Comment: Just for the record I re-imaged at least 4 times and had the read-write problem so I feel I was thorough enough to justify this post.

Comment: It happened again [Here are some photos I took of the logs.](http://imgur.com/a/9Uqn5)

Comment: @ReidA : Okay, have a look at what I added above.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As soon as I have time to mess with my Pi again I'll investigate. Fortunately I dual boot Linux Mint on my laptop with the SD slot. I'll try to be extra careful in waiting to power off and see if that helps increase reliability but I'm sure at least one corruption happened during a restart without powerdown. I'd upvote you if I had the reputation required, guess it doesn't transfer between stack sites.

Comment: I ran the commands on the card like you suggested to no effect. I also tried booting from a different card but as soon as I reboot (using reboot command from terminal) it failed exactly like the first one. Should my PI be suspect at this point or the power unit? I'm feeling like the failure is a lot more consistent now before I was able to occasionally reboot without corruption.

Comment: @ReidA Yeah :( I see *way* too many people here complaining of this issue and making it clear they are shutting down and rebooting correctly for them all to be wrong -- at least a few a week. Meanwhile, I've had mine for ~6 months, work with it everyday, had power failures (one this morning, in fact) and never had a problem. There are rumors that rpi's from China are lower quality.  I can't say whether that is true (or how to tell them apart), but Element 14 actually brag on their site now that they only sell the UK ones.  **But...**

Comment: ...while if `e2fsck -c` on another linux box says your partition is clean, your partition is clean, that does not include the first vfat partition.  Based on your description, it seems unlikely to me that is the issue, *but* you never know.  I don't work with vfat much, I imagine you can verify that in  a windows box.  At least then when you mail it back you can say you were thorough.  Give them this url too.

Comment: Guess I'll see about returning the Pi (fulfillment by Amazon, expecting no problems with customer support) The vendor name on Amazon is listed as "savingCOST", do you think it's worth it to ask for a refund and buy a new unit from E14?

Comment: @ReidA Might be worthwhile.  I can't find the E14 page I'm sure I saw recently, but this thread: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=48784 claims they did move production back to the UK, and there are various news stories about it too -- surely there's a reason beyond patriotism at work there.  Someone on that thread also claims to have a UK pi and a China pi (stickered -- probably on the little white box it came in) and an SD card that works in the former but not the latter.  I'm sure if you inquire with E14 they will give you an honest answer.

Comment: The advice to "put the SD card into another linux system" was very helpful. In my case, the system was booting read-only due to copying my disk image to a slightly smaller SD, though both source and destination are labelled as 16GB cards. The slight difference became evident when I used `sudo parted /dev/sdc print` to confirm that I had the right device for the SD card. Fixed with `resize2fs` and `parted`.

Answer (score -2):

I was stuck in read only mode as well. In my case I was able to force read only mode to work by running

```
mount -o remount, rw /
```

But then all sorts of other aspects didn't work. So to fix for good, I erased the SD card using disk utility on MacOS, as seen below:

[image]

Then I used Etcher to write the image ([Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) in my case).

Comment: I do not understand. You formated the SD Card with a FAT file system and then mount the image? What image? Which partition do you format? The root partition needs an ext4 file system.

Comment: I'm not very technically skilled with file systems, so a lot of this is going over my head. The image in my case was [raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and I used Etcher to mount it

Comment: You don't need to format your SD-card before writing an image to it. When you write an image to an SD-card, it erases the existing partitions/formatting and rewrites it with that of the image file.

(Also, Etcher writes images, mounting an image is something different.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Max. Despite what you say, this method solved my problem even after I had tried using just Etcher a couple times before (with no luck). Bottom line is that I had this issue, found a solution, and posted here to try and help out the next guy.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, but it's important to know that the problem you encountered has nothing to do with formatting your card before writing an image to it. If you had this problem over and over again, you might have bad blocks on your SD-card that corrupt really quickly and then it's just a matter of time before it corrupts again. But hey, I'm still glad you got it to work ;)

Comment: The problem happened because I was abusing the raspberry PI: probably it was caused by removing the SD card before shutting down. Simply burning the image to SD with Ether was not solving any issues with my read-only filesystem. The solution was to format prior to using Etcher, as seen above